# PHP code always shows wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP and able to create a Registration form. But the code doesn't working properly. It always goes to else statement of `Username exists Try Again`. Any help appreciated and any explanation greatly welcomed :)

```
function session() {
    $usn = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password']; 
    $email = $_POST['Email'];  

    $con=mysqli_connect("********","***********","**********","*********");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Accounts 
    WHERE username = '$usn'");

    If($result == Null) {
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Accounts (username, password, Email)
        VALUES ('$usn', '$pwd','$email')");

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username = '$usn'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if (($row['password']==$pwd) and ($row['Email']==$email)) {
                echo "Registration Success";
            }
            else {
                echo "Registration Failed";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Username Exists Try Again";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML please?

Comment: `$result` will be never null, I'd rather check for num_rows

Comment: Please, please, please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  If you don't, someone could login as `'; DROP TABLES Accounts; -- `, or worse.

Comment: What could be the right way of conditioning over there?

Comment: Why closing, guys? The problem is described, the OP is working with us, the first obvious problem has been spotted and answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$result` will never be null. You need to check for something like number of rows -

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

If that is greater than 0, then go to your else.

Comment: Exactly what I said, +1

Comment: We must've been typing at the same time @Fabio :)

Comment: Problem is: There is an INSERT query that is never been checked for success, and after that a SELECT which does not find the inserted user. I guess the INSERT is giving errors.

Comment: @sven nop, the else is for the first if, check curly braces

Comment: He never gets there @Sven, because `$results` is never NULL.

Comment: Only if you want to enter the Curly-Bracket War @Sven ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard It should be somehow consistent, shouldn't it? I can live with any style possible, but one: "Random whitespace indentation". And this is the case here.

Comment: Don't get me wrong @Sven - I agree whole-heartedly. Proper formatting would not have helped the OP spot the problem though. Us yes, OP no.

Comment: Thanks to the guy formatting the code then. Proper formatting is a quality beginners don't care about, and probably for good reasons. They have to struggle with plenty of other stuff, whitespace is the least of their concerns.